# how do I get the upper text in a facebook open graph action story?

Tags: facebook-opengraph

Take a look at the action link story examples in the Facebook documentation here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actionlinks/ . Note this isn't a question about action links, but rather about other aspects of the example on this page; I'm not using action links, just publishing open graph actions.

In the "Story with Action Link" example, there's a line of text between the action and the action object below; the line is "You have to give this a try! Delicious!" This line of text does not appear in the second example, "Story after Action Link Clicked."

How do I get that line of text to appear? I have action posts working, but I can only get the result in the second example.

I noticed in my Action definition that under "optional properties," there's a field called "message." I tried setting that, but it didn't come out. Is there something else I should be setting to use this extra text field? Is this text field only available if you are using action links, or can I use it without them?

Comment: I apologize for spamming the Java tag, but facebook.stackoverflow.com wouldn't alow me to post this question without also including a non-facebook related tag.  Bug: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151440/why-does-a-question-on-facebook-stackoverflow-require-a-non-facebook-tag .

Answer (score 2):

The text set in "message" field comes up in activity the way you want on timeline as personalised message , but your opengraph action should be approved with "user messages" property.

Comment: `$facebook->api("me/app-name:action","POST",array('object'=>"$object_url",'message'=>"$message",'access_token'=>$access_token));` this works for me